# Web scraping and multi-threading in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, programming, interoperability, data-acquisition, webtools

I'm working in some web scraping using Mathematica, and today, to speed-up the process, I used bash commands (xargs with parallel options with curl and wget) using `ReadList` or `Run`. 
I would like to do all this inside Mathematica, but I miss multi-thread capability with asynchronous evaluation. I could use more cores, but it's not the answer because the lag is due to time lag, not lack of processor capacity.

In bash I can do things like:

```
cat url.txt | xargs - n1 - P20 wget
```

Even with 4 cores it distribute the download process in 20 processes.

In Mathematica I can do this:

```
data = ParallelMap[Import,urlList]
```

But you get limited to cores number.

I thought that it would be natural to be multi-threaded if Mathematica is able to use multiple cores.
Any clues?

Comment: Did you try LaunchKernels[n]?

Comment: I think at some point one has to accept that *Mathematica* is not the best tool for every possible job. Here's an idea, though: why not take the source code of `wget` or `aria2`, patch it, and compile it as a *MathLink* executable or a "Wolfram Library" for use with *LibraryLink*?

Comment: Hi Belisairus. Great tip!.. I'll make some tests and put what I get. It appears to works.

Comment: @OleksandrR. interesting idea. I'm wondering how nightmarish that would be ... Obviously, the functionality could be mapped to options/arguments, not simple, but it may be doable.

Comment: @OleksandrR. seems easier to just call them via the command line from mathematica...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Mathematica 9, you can now use [URLFetchAsynchronous](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/URLFetchAsynchronous.html?q=URLFetchAsynchronous&lang=en) and [URLSaveAsynchronous](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/URLSaveAsynchronous.html). These perform the HTTP request asynchronously in threads.

Comment: And you can keep track of how many threads you are using with  `Length@AsynchronousTasks[]`

Answer (score 6):

tks @belisarius!
There is the improved code.

```
CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[16];
ParallelMap[Import,urlList]
```

My mistake was to think that the number of kernels was limited by the number of cores.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 11 see **URLSubmit** and **URLDownloadSubmit**